# How to partially disable/ignore pylint rules?

Tags: python, pylint, pep8

Many of my scripts parse command line arguments inside the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block. I'm using 'normal' variable names there, e.g. `parser`. As this is not in any function, pylint will throw `C0103: invalid constant name <variable>`. Since I'm not really using those variables as constants (just parsing arguments), I'd find it a bit weird to use allcaps here.

Is there a way to partially disable pylint rules so as to not throw C0103 when inside the  `if __name__ == '__main__'` block?

What I want is the following:

```
import argparse

PI = 3.14 # <--- should give no C0103
e = 2.71 # <-- should throw C0103

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser() # <-- should give NO C0103
    PARSER = argparse.ArgumentParser() # <-- should optionally give C0103 (wrong variable name)
```

Thanks a lot :-).

Comment: Write a `main` function and call that? Dunno if there's a better way.

Comment: That's circumventing the problem, not fixing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be possible to achieve by wrapping the **main** method with pylint comments.

```
import argparse
# pylint: disable=C0103
PI = 3.14 # <--- should give no C0103
# pylint: enable=C0103
e = 2.71 # <-- should throw C0103

# pylint: disable=C0103
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser() # <-- should give NO C0103
    PARSER = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# pylint: enable=C0103
```